# Solution to set background-image using [shortcode]?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, background-image, shortcode

- I'd like to set a random background-image into a `<div>`Container`</div>`

  - To keep it simple I installed a plugin using [shortcode] to display random images. This works fine.
  - How to get the shortcode `[wp-image-refresh]` working together with `background-image:url(...)`
  - I tried it even as inline-style with no result.

This is what I have:

HTML

```
<div class="header_random-image">
   <div id="hero"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hero {
  background-image: url('<?php echo do_shortcode("[wp-image-refresh]"); ?>');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 30%;
  height:70vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -65px;
}
```

Another try with no result: Inline-style

```
<div class="header_random-image">
        <div style="background-image: url('<?php echo do_shortcode("[wp-image-refresh]"); ?>')"></div>
</div>
```

Could anybody be so kind to help? Or does anybody has a simple solution to place div-random-background-images?

Best from Berlin

Comment: When you say no result, do you mean it doesn't output anything? Might be an error with how you're calling the shortcode. Have you tried `url("<?php echo do_shortcode('[wp-image-refresh]'); ?>");`

Comment: It should work with inline style. Are you sure that shortcode outputs what you're expecting it to? Are you sure the result is valid CSS? (Proper path, etc...). Also, make sure you place this in either a template or a post/page content that does get parsed interpreted by WordPress. Shortcodes are not allowed anywhere by default. For example, if you try to add shortcodes in a text-widget, you need to enable them first: `add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );`

Comment: Is the CSS section in `<style>` tags in your `<head>` tags inside `header.php`, just a question if not that could be your answer

Comment: Otherwise add `[wp-image-refresh]` as a plain shortcode in a `post` and, tell use what it outputs on the front end :)

Comment: The issue you are facing because sortcode <?php echo do_shortcode("[wp-image-refresh]"); ?>
actually print image with in a img tag , like this

 <img class="" src="http:www.xyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/schoolbreak-1-300x109.png" alt="test">

as you are setting the image as a background so this will not work because here you only needed image source not the entire image block.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I guess @Balwant mentioned the real Shortcode-Problem!

Any idea how to realize the smart background-image behavior as I want it for my hero-image like `background-size: cover`; `background-position: 50% 30%` etc. including a randomizer (and including WP's responsive image-logic as well?)

Best
Tibor

@AndyHolmes
I tried this and several different combinations with no result.
@AndreiGheorghiu
No result with inline-style. Widgets and shortcodes are working well.
@ColinGell
CSS Section is on its right place and Shortcode works well in posts.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases your CSS code will be served in a static file, thus the php code won't execute.

As the inline example doesn't work either, I guess the short code does not return an image url but a full image tag instead. The plugin's description
confirms this assumption. [WP-IMAGE-REFRESH](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-image-refresh/)

You could try this:

PHP

```
<div class="header_random-image">
   <?php echo do_shortcode("[wp-image-refresh class='hero_class']"); ?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header_random-image {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hero_class {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

This should display the image. You'd still have to center it if you want (use flex-box) and check for problems caused on different screen sizes depending on the side ratio of your uploaded images and solve them with some Javascript.

## Alternative

Use ACF Pro and add a [gallery field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/gallery-field/) to your posts/pages or an [option page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_add_options_page/) if you want the same images on all views.

PHP

```
<?php 
    $images = get_field('name-of-your-gallery-field');
    shuffle($images);
    $imageUrl = images[0]['url'];
<div class="header_random-image">
    <div style="background-image: url('<?= $imageUrl ?>"); ?>')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much marcelgro

I solved my problem following your advice. I made some changes to work fine for me like the desired background-image. Random-Plugin works fine, the trick was the embedded .hero_class

PHP
`<div class="header_random-image">
 <?php echo do_shortcode("[wp-image-refresh class='hero_class']"); ?>
</div>`

CSS
`.header_random-image {
  height:65vh;
}
.hero_class {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 30%;
}`